# Imported module pyperclip in .py file showing ModuleNotFoundError when run in windows command prompt

Tags: python, command-line

I'm quite new to python and completely new to executing python code anywhere outside the vs code terminal I'm comfortable with.

I'm reading and following along with Al Sweigart's Automate the Boring Stuff With Python Book, and I'm at chapter 9 where there is a follow-along project of creating a multi-clip board.

Basically, the project is creating a program that uses the shelve, sys and pyperclip modules to store text that is from the clipboard on an external file in dictionary format. Here is it explained in the book:

> The program will save each piece of clipboard text under a keyword. For example, when you run py mcb.pyw save spam, the current contents of the clipboard will be saved with the keyword spam. This text can later be loaded to the clipboard again by running py mcb.pyw spam. And if the user forgets what keywords they have, they can run py mcb.pyw list to copy a list of all keywords to the clipboard.

> Here’s what the program does:

> The command line argument for the keyword is checked.
> If the argument is save, then the clipboard contents are saved to the keyword.
> If the argument is list, then all the keywords are copied to the clipboard.
> Otherwise, the text for the keyword is copied to the clipboard.

I'm completely new to this, so executing from command prompt is a bit intimidating. What I have done is navigated using cd  in command prompt. I then type in 'py.exe mcb226.pyw' (i named mine slightly differently). The file does indeed run but i get this error (in the command prompt):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "mcb226.pyw", line 10, in <module>
      import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

This confuses me because. What does this even mean? I have pyperclip installed (which I installed via the Anaconda prompt system, I run vs code through Anaconda). Do I have to install it through the command prompt?

Heres my code in the mcb226.pyw file:

```
#! python3
# mcb.pyw - Saves and loads pieces of text to the clipboard
# usage: py.exe mcb226.pyw save <keyword> - Saves clipboard to keyword
#        py.exe mcb226.pyw <keyword> - Loads keyword to clipboard
#        py.exe mcb226.pyw list - loads all keywords to clipboard

import shelve
import sys
import pyperclip

path = 'C:/Users/adamt/Desktop/testfolder/mcb/mcb'
mcbShelf = shelve.open(path)
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1].lower() == 'save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]] = pyperclip.paste()
elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
    # if the sys. argument list is 2, this must either be 'list' or to ask to get a variable, since its only mcb226.pyw list or mcb225.pyw spam
    if sys.argv[1].lower() == 'list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[2] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]])

mcbShelf.close()
```

Comment: You need to install `pyperclip`.

Comment: @TomKarzes I already have installed pyperclip through the anaconda prompt, and I can use it in my python code. I'll edit the question to clarify, though. Do I have to reinstall it on the command prompt?

Comment: Is it possibly you have multiple Python installations?  Your script doesn't invoke Python through an absolute path.  Maybe try using an absolute path so you know exactly what it's running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyperclip` should be installed in the environment where you are running your code. `pyperclip` package is not installed in the `site-packages` directory of python installation which you are using to run your script.

To solve this issue, run below command on the terminal where you are running your code.

```
pip install pyperclip
```